# req.body undefined and express api testing using angular

Tags: angularjs, express, mongoose

I am practicing API and having a small issue. Can someone please have a look the code below and let me know why req.body logs undefined when I do POST request using angular $http on the client side? also try a simple jquery AJAX request to have the same result.

```
//------------------  back-end
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();

//connect DB
var mongoURI = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/Ecomm_db';
mongoose.connect(mongoURI);

//express config
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//DB setup
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Product = new Schema({  
    title: { type: String, required: true },  
    description: { type: String, required: true },  
    style: { type: String, unique: true },  
    modified: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var ProductModel = mongoose.model('Product', Product); 


//API
app.post('/api/products', function (req, res){
  var product;
  console.log("POST: ");
  console.log(req.body);
  product = new ProductModel({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    style: req.body.style,
  });
  product.save(function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      return console.log("created");
    } else {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  });
  return res.send(product);
});

//--------------------------- client-end
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/products',
      data: {
        title: "my t-shirts",
        description: "super good",
        style: "my style"
      }
    }).then(function (response){
      console.log('POST response',response);
    }, function (err){
      console.log('err:', err);
    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use module 'body-parser'

`var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: oh Helen. you are the saver. it fixed it.

Comment: @jhlosin i'm glad to help